# Problem replicating a comparison between CE and MSE

Tags: neural-network, cross-entropy, mse

I tried to reimplement a visual comparison of CE and MSE losses from a paper by Glorot and Bengio, *Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks*. My objective would be to obtain the same figure as in Sect. 4.1, Fig. 5.

See here: https://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf

The network description is a bit ambiguous and I came to this PyTorch network

```py
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Sigmoid()
)
```

Then I set the parameters with this function:

```py
def set_weights(model, w1, w2):
    (w1, w2) = torch.FloatTensor([w1, w2])
    model[0].weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([[w1]]))
    model[2].weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([[w2]]))
    return model
```

The description of the computation of the losses in the paper is even more ambiguous. I tried many possible loss computations between the input and output and the one that comes closest to their figure (Fig. 5) is this one:

```py
def losses(model, trials=10000):
    """
    The random input is the truth
    """
    p = torch.unsqueeze(torch.rand(trials), dim=1)  # random input signal prob. relative to class 1
    # m = model(torch.unsqueeze(torch.rand(trials), dim=1))
    m = model(p)
    p_0 = (p < 0.5).float()  # class 0
    p_1 = (p >= 0.5).float()  # class 1
    p = p_0 * (1 - p) + p_1 * p  # prob. relative to class 0 and 1
    m = p_0 * (1 - m) + p_1 * m
    ce = -torch.mean(p * torch.log(m))
    mse = torch.mean((p - m)**2)
    return ce, mse
```

I varied the weights with

```py
ce_l = []
mse_l = []
x_l = torch.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
y_l = torch.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
for w1, w2 in [(w1, w2) for w1 in x_l for w2 in y_l]:
    model = set_weights(model, w1, w2)
    ce, mse = losses(model)
    ce_l += [ce]
    mse_l += [mse]
```

and I plotted the losses on a 3-D figure. But my result is still not as sharp as the original figure. See here: [Losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T63n8.png)

Has somebody an idea?

Added the code to reproduce my figure: https://github.com/pnugues/ce_mse/blob/main/ce_mse.ipynb
as well as a notebook that uses PyTorch's loss functions `BCELoss` and `MSELoss` as is: https://github.com/pnugues/ce_mse/blob/main/ce_mse_pytorch_losses.ipynb

I found the answer to my question with the help of Xavier Glorot. The model is simpler than the one I used and has no hyperbolic tangents:

```py
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False),
    nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False),
    nn.Sigmoid()
)
```

Using it I could replicate the figure. See the notebook here: https://github.com/pnugues/ce_mse/blob/main/ce_mse_pytorch_losses_xglorot.ipynb